# Linux Kernel pre-silicon bringup

Tags: linux-kernel, mips, linux-device-driver

Will Linux Kerenl jump to calibrate_delay when console_init is commented ? Debugging is difficult in the bringup environment on SOC hence this question.

I have added printascii patch to bringup my kernel (MIPS-InterAptiv) and I am seeing that prints are coming till init_IRQ and after that no prints are coming. and could see that processor is not coming out of console_init ; wanted to check with console_init commented out ? Also since printascii patch is present my further prints will come . Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: "Bringup" as in troubleshooting new hardware? Or an ordinary boot?  What is *"pre-silicon"* supposed to mean, simulation before you commit to a spin?

Comment: yes, linux bringup on simulation

Answer (score 1):

On MIPS, **`calibrate_delay()`** is called from within **[`start_secondary()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/mips/kernel/smp.c?v=3.8;a=mips#L120)**,
which is called from **[`arch/mips/kernel/head.S`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/mips/kernel/head.S?v=3.8;a=mips#L227)**

If you intend to skip running the calibration loop, then you can pass
**`lpj=<pre-calculated-lpj-value>`** on the kernel cmd-line(bootargs).

**`lpj`** stands for **loops-per-jiffies**. This is usually calculated by running the CPU in short a loop during boot-up. The `lpj` value thus calculated will be printed out to console as :

`[0.001119] Calibrating delay loop... 364.48 BogoMIPS (lpj=1425408)`

The exact value of **`lpj`** will differ from device to device and depends upon the CPU-freq as well.